# MIPS Instructions on signed bits

Tags: mips

I multiplied two numbers(one negative, and one positive) in MIPS and when I printed the value to the console, it correctly interpreted it as a negative integer. However, after I did this instruction:

```
andi $t3, $t3, 255
```

(I did this to access only the first 8 bits)

The value printed to my console was positive. Is there a way to maintain the signed value of a binary number through various instructions/operations in MIPS?

Comment: I know nothing about this, but Q6 on [this](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~virgil/cs470/Labs/Lab6.pdf) seems possibly related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in this way (i.e. `and`ing).

A negative number has the MSB set (i.e. `0x80000000`). When you do the `andi`, you lose this bit (i.e. destroy it).

Consider `-1`, which is `0xFFFFFFFF`. When you and against 255 (`0x000000FF`), you get `0x000000FF`, which is 255 decimal.

Consider `-2`, which is `0xFFFFFFFE`. When you and against 255 (`0x000000FF`), you get `0x000000FE`, which is 254 decimal.

If you had a *signed* `char` [as in C], the range is -128 (`0x80`) to 127 (`0x7F`).

You could sign extend this with:

```
    sll     $t3,$t3,24              # force sign bit of byte into sign of word
    sra     $t3,$t3,24              # sign extend the register
```

But, this only works for the range of the signed char value. For example, if you originally had 511 (`0x000001FF`) and did this, you'll end up with -1, which is incorrect.

So, really, doing the `andi` invalidates the question, so to speak.

You can retain the original *signedness* by preserving the original value, in parallel, and doing something with it later.